# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Users/

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can Someone please Help ??
I am asked to pick up the team, teamid, pennants, and worldseries columns from the champs and teamstats tables. and print the number of baseball teams in the champs table. I have 2 files as following. I keep getting warnings saying Warning:mysqli_num_rows()expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Users/

```
<?php //FIRST FILE: mysqli_connect.php

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'happy');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'baseball_stats');

// Make the connection:
 $dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR 
 die ('Could not connect to
 MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

 // Set the encoding...
 mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
 ?>
 //// SECOND FILE 
 <?php

require ('a9mysqli_connect.php');

$query = "SELECT t.team AS T, t.team_id AS Ti, c.pennants AS P, 
c.worldseries AS W from `teamstats` as t join `champs` as c on 
t.team_id = c.team_id;";

 $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query); 

 // Count the number of returned rows:
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//Create an HTML table for displaying the query results:

if ($num > 0) {  // If it ran OK, display the records.
echo "<p>There are currently $num baseball teams.</p>"; 

echo '<table align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Team</b></td>
<td align="right"><b>Team ID</b></td>
<td align="right"><b>Pennants </b></td>
<td align="right"><b>WorldSeries </b></td>
</tr>'
;
//Fetch and print each returned record:

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo '<tr><td align="left">' . $row['T'] . '</td><td align= "left">' . 
$row['Ti'] . '</td><td align= "left">' . $row['P'] . '</td><td align= 
"left">' . $row['W'] . '</td></tr>'; 
 }
 echo '</table>';
mysqli_free_result ($result);
}
else { //If it didnot run OK.

 // Public message:
 echo '<p class="error"> There are currently no baseball teams in
 the database.</p>';
  echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $query . 
  '</p>';
 }
 mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Comment: why `@mysqli_query (` and not `mysqli_query (`

Comment: your querry failed, debug that

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_query](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) for successful queries it will return TRUE, FALSE on failure, you need to check if the query was successful, in your code check 
`if ($result)`

**UPDATE**

This happens because you use `$dbc` which is declared in another file `mysqli_connect.php`

```
<?php //FIRST FILE: mysqli_connect.php

DEFINE('DB_USER', 'happy');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'baseball_stats');

// Make the connection:
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR
die ('Could not connect to
 MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

// Set the encoding...
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
?>
```

Then in the second php file you require the file like `require ('a9mysqli_connect.php');` and this file doesn't exists. running the code as it is i got the following error.

[image]

The error is clear you are passing a variable that doesn't exists to `mysqli_query`, you need to require the file correctly.

```
<?php

require('mysqli_connect.php');
$query = "SELECT t.team AS T, t.team_id AS Ti, c.pennants AS P, 
c.worldseries AS W from `teamstats` as t join `champs` as c on 
t.team_id = c.team_id;";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); // remove @
if ($result) {
    // Count the number of returned rows:
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    //Create an HTML table for displaying the query results:

    if ($num > 0) {  // If it ran OK, display the records.
        echo "<p>There are currently $num baseball teams.</p>";

        echo '<table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left"><b>Team</b></td>
                    <td align="right"><b>Team ID</b></td>
                    <td align="right"><b>Pennants </b></td>
                    <td align="right"><b>WorldSeries </b></td>
                </tr>';
        //Fetch and print each returned record:

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<tr><td align="left">' . $row['T'] . '</td><td align= "left">' . $row['Ti'] . '</td><td align= "left">' . $row['P'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['W'] . '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else { //If it didnot run OK.

        // Public message:
        echo '<p class="error"> There are currently no baseball teams in the database.</p>';
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $query .
            '</p>';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
} else {
    echo 'Something wrong happened!!!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @julekgwa -- removed @ and tried if statement, still get the same warning

Comment: You don't understand what does an error message mean.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I understand clearly what the error is about,  this statement ` $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);` returns null because either `$dbc` is not defined as it was defined in `mysqli_connect.php` but OP used `require ('a9mysqli_connect.php');` in the second file.

Comment: Why it says "There are currently no baseball teams in
 the database" then?

Comment: where does it say it that?

Comment: @YourCommonSense maybe I'm missing something here

Answer (score 0):

1. See [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) on php.net under "Description":

> For non-DML queries (not INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE), this function is
>   similar to calling mysqli_real_query() followed by either
>   mysqli_use_result() or mysqli_store_result().

2. See [mysqli_store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) on php.net under "Return Values":

> Also possible reason for this function returning FALSE after
>   successfull call to mysqli_query() can be too large result set (memory
>   for it cannot be allocated). If mysqli_field_count() returns a
>   non-zero value, the statement should have produced a non-empty result
>   set.

I also wrote a left join sql query, maybe you can use it. You used the **JOIN** keyword. I used **LEFT JOIN**. But I tested also with **JOIN**. It worked, so your query is ok.

***Description***:
Read all teams (from **teams** table) and, for each of them, also the corresponding champs details (pennants and worldseries from **champs** table). But only the teams who's team_id also in champs exists (`ISNULL(c.team_id) = FALSE`).

```
SELECT 
    t.team AS T,
    t.team_id AS Ti,
    c.pennants AS P,
    c.worldseries AS W
FROM
    `teamstats` AS t
        LEFT JOIN
    `champs` AS c ON t.team_id = c.team_id
WHERE
    ISNULL(c.team_id) = FALSE
;
```